# Return specific portion of a string

Tags: javascript

I currently have a string that returns this set of data:

```
  7,438,686 IN        NONRESET CNTR     
  172,269 IN          RESET CNTR1       
  0 IN                RESET CNTR2       
  18,895,900 CM       NONRESET CNTR     
  437,602 CM          RESET CNTR1       
  10 CM               RESET CNTR2       
  SELECTED ITEMS      PASSWORD LEVEL
```

The only data I care to see is the 'RESET CNTR2' value of '10 CM'. How can I use JavaScript to create a string with only the '10 CM'? The '10 CM' is dynamic data.

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Is this the *only* way you can receive the data? It's going to make your life easier if that can be turned into an object, instead of using string manipulation and potentially regex

Comment: The data belongs to a printer's web page. The webpage contains all this data in an HTML <pre> tag. I use something like: threeHundredData = $("pre").html(); to grab this information and store in the threeHundredData string. This method works for me because I do use all this data for one portion of my electron program. But for another portion I only need the '10CM' string. Hopefully this makes sense.

Comment: What about the first occurrence `0 IN`.  Is this always going to be formatted like this?

Comment: If the print counter has just been reset it will display '0 IN' or '0 CM'. To answer your question in short, yes.

Answer (score 1):

You can regular expressions to extract that piece of text. Playing around a bit with a [regex tester](https://regex101.com/) shows that

```
/((\d+) CM) *RESET CNTR2/
```

is the regex you are probably looking for. Then, to use this, you simply do:

```
var regex = /((\d+) CM) *RESET CNTR2/;
var string = "7,438,686 IN ....";
var captureGroups = regex.exec(string);
```

Then `captureGroups[1]` contains `10 CM` and `captureGroups[2]` contains just `10`.

Answer (score 0):

`RESET CNTR2` appears twice in your data set. Does the value have to be concatenated with `CM`, and are the values all on a new line?

The following can solve your issue:

```js
    const key = 'RESET CNTR2',
        metrics = 'CM';
    
    const data = `
      7,438,686 IN        NONRESET CNTR     
      172,269 IN          RESET CNTR1       
      0 IN                RESET CNTR2       
      18,895,900 CM       NONRESET CNTR     
      437,602 CM          RESET CNTR1       
      10 CM               RESET CNTR2       
      SELECTED ITEMS      PASSWORD LEVEL 
    `.split('\n');
    
    let index = data.findIndex(str => str.indexOf(key) > -1 && str.indexOf(metrics) > -1);
    
    let row = data[index];
    
    let val = row.substring(0, row.indexOf(metrics));
    
    console.log(val);
    
    // or if you need the 'cm' part
    
    console.log(`${val}${metrics}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do it

```
var str = `7,438,686 IN        NONRESET CNTR     
  172,269 IN          RESET CNTR1       
  0 IN                RESET CNTR2       
  18,895,900 CM       NONRESET CNTR     
  437,602 CM          RESET CNTR1       
  10 CM               RESET CNTR2       
  SELECTED ITEMS      PASSWORD LEVEL `;

var rows = str.split('\n');
for ( var n in rows ) {
   if ( rows[n].indexOf('RESET CNTR2') != -1 ) {
        var rowbits = rows[n].trim().split('  ');
      if( parseInt(rowbits[0]) > 0 ){
        console.log(rowbits[0]);
      }
   }
}
```

fiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/jd3Lxgj3/